# How can I send FirebaseUser information on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

So I have a facebook login on my app, I want to send the user information, the name and the photo to my Firebase. I was able to retrieve this information using "displayName" and "photoUrl", but when I try to upload to the "users" database its not creating the collection. Do you guys know how can I do it?

```
class ConfAuthScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    FirebaseUser _currentUser;

    ConfAuthScreen(this._currentUser);

    Future<FirebaseUser> addData() async {
    if (_currentUser != null) return _currentUser;
     Firestore.instance.collection('users').add(
        {'name': _currentUser.displayName, 'photo': _currentUser.photoUrl});
     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              body: Center(
               child: Container(
                   child: Column(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 150.0,
                width: 150.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        image: NetworkImage(_currentUser.photoUrl))),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Bem vindo(a) ${_currentUser.displayName}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15.0,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ChatScreen(_currentUser)));
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "OK",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ))
            ])),
      ),
    );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get an instance of the current user

`FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();`

and then you can continue to add your user data if `user!=null`

`Firestore.instance.collection('users')
  .document('${user.uid}'.add(
        {
          'name': _currentUser.displayName,
          'photo': _currentUser.photoUrl
    });
     }`

Comment: Thanks Griffins, I actually needed to substitute "add" for "setData", but still not working. I can display the User info on screen but can't upload to firebase.

Comment: found a way to do it, changed "user" for "firebaseuser" and instead of "user.uid" used "firebaseuser.uid".